# Is there a way to ignore the requirejs imports?

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, babeljs

I have an auto-generated file that uses RequireJS. However, I am using this file in a project that uses the ES2015 import with Webpack. The objects that are being imported are exposed globally.

```
define(["ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/text", "ace/mode/text_highlight_rules"], function(oop, mText, mTextHighlightRules) {
// I only want to expose the logic within this scope
}
```

Is it possible to tell Babel to ignore these import statements for this specific file?

Also, I have found a module that converts RequireJS syntax to ES2015 syntax. If the answer to the first question is no, would it be possible to ignore ES2015 import statements:

```
var oop = require('ace/lib/oop');
var mText = require('ace/mode/text');
var mTextHighlightRules = require('ace/mode/text_highlight_rules');
```

Any imports from the ace module can be ignored as they are defined globally.

Thanks!

Comment: "auto-generated"... who is generating? can't you generate it in UMD format? wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: Auto-generated by Xtext, which unfortunately I cannot modify. Unless I do a PR of course.